# how can i make xml for myXMLHttpRequest.responseXML with XmlTextWriter in .ashx

Tags: .net, ashx, xmltextwriter

i try it in my .ashx page but i got error 500 in myXMLHttpRequest.status and i can't understand where is the problem. a simple code for generate a simple xml would be very good. like:

```
<properties>
 <property>
   <address>812 Gwyn Ave</address>    
 </property>
 <property>
   <address>3308 James Ave S</address>    
 </property>
</properties>
```

@  here is my solution (sql code works fine):

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Clear();            
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter();
        string user_id = context.Request.Params["user_id"];          

        string connectionString = ("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=user_city;Integrated Security=True");
        string queryString = "select * from city_buildings where user_id=" + user_id + ";";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {                
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            try
            {               
                writer.WriteStartElement("buildings");
                while (reader.Read())
                {                        
                    writer.WriteStartElement("building");

                      writer.WriteElementString("user_id",Convert.ToString( reader[0]));

                    writer.WriteEndElement();

                }
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndDocument();
                writer.Flush();
                writer.Close();
            }
            finally
            {                   
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you share with us the solution you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont have access to visual studio right now so doing this from top of the head. Should five you a starting point.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";

    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(context.Response.OutputStream))
    {
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        // do xmlwriter stuff here.
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I indeed did mean to put OutputStream there. I updated the example to reflect this.

Have been looking at your code briefly. I can see you do not output the result of the xmlwriter to the HttpResponse. (what my example does by binding it to `Context.Response.OutputStream`) That should be a reason why it won't work. Altough why the 500 error occurs i don't see. Maybe you should run in visual studio to see if any errors occur that will cause this.

Also i noticed your use of `reader[0]`. Event tough this might technicly be correct i will suggest you use a safer method like the following:

```
int fieldIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("address");
reader.GetString(fieldIndex);
```

This will ensure you will always get the desired field from the query. Even if in the future you decide to change the database schema to add some more columns.

Comment: in your code (context.Response.ResponseStream) ResponseStream is unknown in my visual studio ! do you mean OutputStream ?